# How do I fix loading the wrong firmware image onto a Godox flash?

Tags: godox, firmware

By mistake, I updated my Godox TT685 II-C flash with the v1.3 firmware for the V860.

Is there a way to fix this? Where can I get the correct Godox TT685 II-C firmware image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to fix an E9 error is to reload the correct firmware image onto your flash, if you can.

But since it's such a new model, Godox hasn't published any firmware updates on [their website](https://godox.com/support/search/?keyword=TT685%20II), yet. You will probably have to contact Godox support, or the retailer where you purchased your flash, to get a copy of the right firmware image file to use with the G3 updater.  If you got a Flashpoint version from Adorama, contact [Flashpointlighting support](https://www.flashpointlighting.com/support/) instead of Adorama's sales support.  They may ask you to exchange your unit instead.